# How to add CSS class to <select> element on a Symfony generated form?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm testing the FormBuilder. When I generate a `<select>` field, I can't figure out how to add a CSS class to this HTML element: Symfony adds the class to the parent `<div>`.

Here is my FormBuilder Class :

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
        // (...)
        ->add('roles', CollectionType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'MyClass'],
                'entry_type'   => ChoiceType::class,
                'entry_options'  => [
                    'label' => 'Select a role',
                    'label_attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-label'
                    ],
                    'choices' => [
                        'User' => 'ROLE_USER',
                        'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                    ],
                ],
            ])
        // (...)
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML rendering :

```html
<div id="user_roles" class="MyClass">
    <div>
        <label class="form-label required" for="user_roles_0">Select a role</label>
        <select id="user_roles_0" name="user[roles][0]">
            <option value="ROLE_USER" selected="selected">User</option>
            <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">Admin</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML rendering I would like to get :

```html
<div id="user_roles">
    <div>
        <label class="form-label required" for="user_roles_0">Select a role</label>
        <select id="user_roles_0" name="user[roles][0]" class="MyClass">
            <option value="ROLE_USER" selected="selected">User</option>
            <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">Admin</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried to modify the class from the Twig template, but the result is the same.

Is there a way to assign this class to the `<select>` using the FormBuilder?

Comment: Can you show how you go about rendering the form in the html? Because you could do something like `{{  form_widget(form.name, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'MyClass' } })  }}`

Comment: I've tried this and the result is the same :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the class to the select, move the `attr` array to the `entry_options`:

```
$builder
// (...)
->add('roles', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type'   => ChoiceType::class,
        'entry_options'  => [
            'attr' => ['class' => 'MyClass'],
            'label' => 'Select a role',
            'label_attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-label'
            ],
            'choices' => [
                'User' => 'ROLE_USER',
                'Admin' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
            ],
        ],
    ])
// (...)
```